# How to translate Delphi's “array of string” param to C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, delphi

I'm trying to use DLL that is written in Delphi in my C++ program (Visual Studio 2008).
In DLL documentation function is declared as:

```
function ReadInfo(pRetBuffer: Pointer) : boolean;
```

where **pRetBuffer - pointer to variable of type "array of string" where result is returned**.
How should I declare this parameter (array of string) in c++?

In DLL's documentation I have an example how to use this function in Delphi:

```
function ReadInfo(pRetBuffer: Pointer): boolean; stdcall; external 'SOME.dll'

var
   RetBuffer: array of string;
.
.
.

procedure Test();
var
   Result: Boolean;
begin
.
.
.
   Result := ReadInfo(@RetBuffer);
.
.
.
end;
```

Comment: Technically, a literal translation would be `std::string (*)[N]` (where N is the number of strings). That's a pointer to an array of `N` strings. However, I doubt doing this would be a good idea. Typically, you want to use stdlib containers such as `std::vector<std::string>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that you cannot call that function from C++. A Delphi `array of string` variable is a managed type, private to Delphi. You cannot pass one of those across an interop boundary. It's even dubious for a Delphi host to attempt to call that DLL function.

You'll need to change the function to use valid interop types.

You could use a `SAFEARRAY`.  You could get the DLL to return a pointer to null terminated array of `PChar`. But you'd then need to export a deallocator, or allocate off a shared heap such as the COM heap. Do that with a `BSTR` and you solve the allocation problem at the same time.

Or, as you yourself suggest in the comments, you could use a Delphi DLL act as a bridge.

Comment: Thanks You for Your answer, but is there any way to do this without changing DLL itself? I have no access to DLL source :(

Comment: My first sentence answers that. If this really is `array of string`, then you cannot access that from C++. Why did the author of the DLL do that?

Comment: Have no idea why did he do that :) In DLL's documentation I have a code example in Delphi how to call this function and everyting looks quite easy... Maybe a good solution would be writing "transitional" DLL in Delphi so I could change parameters types and call them from c++?

Comment: I suspect that making a Delphi bridge DLL is the only viable approach. . You'll want to make sure that you use the same version of Delphi so that the string types are compatible. Perhaps it would be helpful if you should the example call to the function so that we can confirm that it really is `array of string`.

Comment: @user3000201: Please provide the documented example that works in Delphi.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I stand by my answer. You cannot call that from anything other than Delphi code. And even then only if your Delphi uses the same string layout at the DLL. That DLL is appallingly designed.

Comment: Even the delphi wrapper dll variant can be tricky and might require using that shared memory manager dll (forgot the name) *on both sides*, depending on what the caller does to that array and the strings.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yes indeed. This DLL is radioactive.